# Perl regexp with $1 and /e

Tags: regex, perl

I'm making a regexp constructor. 
But when running:

```
my $text = 'a a a';
my $replace = '$1/$2-$3';
$text =~ s/(\w) (\w+) (\w+)/$replace/gmi;
```

$text here = '$1/$2-$3';
So $1,$2,$3 are not changed but placed as they are in $replace. How would i make it use $replace content as manually printed replate pattern?

Comment: The code is doing what your are telling it to do. Now what exactly you want from it? `$1` and `$2` have no special meaning if you are using it as a string value in some variable. They are just a part of that string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$replace` is just a string. If you want it to be evaluated as code, you need the `/e` modifier in your substitution. But you also need to prepare your string for the evaluation to interpolate your variables:

```
my $replace = 'qq($1/$2-$3)';
$text =~ s/(\w) (\w+) (\w+)/$replace/gmiee;
```

We use double evaluation to first turn the variable into a string, then to evaluate that string.

However, whenever you find yourself relying on eval, you're probably doing something unnecessary. Eval can be rather evil, as OmnipotentEntity rightly points out, so be very careful about using it.

Comment: "However, whenever you find yourself relying on eval, you're probably doing something unnecessary." Or nefarious.

Comment: Too much working. I've tested with /ee but forgot about quoting $replace content in double quotes / qq.

Comment: @elgato There's probably a better way to do what you are trying to do than this, though.